# how to animate text without dividing letters in spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to animate text in element dynamically but i cant find a way to do that, there is what i tried so far https://jsfiddle.net/yup55u9f/3/ but its not the best way.

i have tried some methods like `split` text into array and push letters in span but it doesn't work.

```js
var i = -1,
    spn = document.querySelectorAll('.spn'),
    stInt;


var setTO = setTimeout(function AnimTxt() {
  stInt = setInterval(function () {
    if (i <= spn.length) {
      i += 1;
      $('.spn').eq(i).css({
        color: "red",
        marginTop: "-10px"
      });

      return false;
    }
  }, 100);
}, 2000);
```

```css
.spn {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    top: 8px;
    left: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.spn:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 16px
}

.spn:nth-of-type(3) {
    left: 27px
}

.spn:nth-of-type(4) {
    left: 42px
}

p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="placeholder-cont">
    <span class="spn">t</span>
    <span class="spn">e</span>
    <span class="spn">x</span>
    <span class="spn">t</span>
</span>
```

Comment: So you want `<span class="spn">name</span>` and then letters get separated into different `span` tags by javascript?

Comment: this would be good and it will be better without separating in new elements, thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried separating letters into `span` tags for now. As for this - *it will be better without separating in new elements* - I can't find a way to achieve this without separating letters into `span`.

```
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
   $(".placeholder-cont").append("<span class='spn'>" + text[i] + "</span>");
}
```

And then animating them using `.each()` and `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval`

```
$(".spn").each(function(index, el) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).css({
      color: "red",
      marginTop: "-10px"
    });
    if (index == (text.length - 1)) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('p').show();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, 100 * index);
});
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/rk3mzae8/).

**EDIT**

In order to remove `position: absolute` I have added to span tags -

```
display: inline-block;
```

and then animated using 'transform' property.

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/rk3mzae8/1/)

Comment: great job, that's better from what i did but my problem is if i added new letters to the span it stuck at the top left, so i want to find some way to animate any letter in span without setting absolute position, thanks for your help.

Comment: @El.oz I have added `display: inline-block` and removed `position:absolute` for `span` elements and hence `margin-top` won't work well now. So instead I have used `transform` css property to animate it to top. Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/rk3mzae8/1/

Comment: dude! your are amazing! this exactly what i want, thanks buddy for your time.

Comment: I am glad to be there for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. You could use `split()` to create array from letters and then use `map()` and `replace()` to wrap each letter in `span` and then `join()` to return to string.

```js
$('.text').html($('.text').text().split('').map(function(e) {
  return e.replace(/[^ ]/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
}).join(''));


$('.text .letter').each(function(i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'translateY(-50px)',
      'color': 'red'
    });
  }, 100 * i);
})
```

```css
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.letter {
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you. just few more questions, in the first argument in `map` function , is that to  trim white space?  and in the second arg what does `$&` do?  thanks.

Comment: If you meant `e` argument in map that is each element in array that you apply map on or in this case it will be each letter, and then on each letter you apply replace function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. In replace first argument is regex that will match all but white space, and second argument is what you will be replacing with, so in this case i will wrap each element `$&` in span.